# How to reproduce the behavior of Mac OS X's dead keys on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, dead-keys

I'm French, but I've chosen to take a `QWERTY` keyboard for my MacBook Pro for many reasons:

- first of all, the `AZERTY` keyboard is not at all ergonomic because it has no numeric keypad, and I must use MAJ or CAPS LOCK to access to the numeric keys ;
- secondly, I've bought this mac for development ; and chars `{`, `}`, etc., are not directly accessible on the Apple `AZERTY` keyboard
- the last thing is that: the diacritics are VERY easy to produce on an Apple keyboard with Mac OS X : `⎇ + c` for a `ç`, for example, and many dead keys easy to use (e.g. `⎇ + e`, then `e` give you an `é`.

So, I have no difficulties to write in my native language with this keyboard under Mac OS X.

BUT, when I boot on Windows 7's Boot Camp partition, or when I use applications from it through VMware Unity, it is no longer the same comfort!

Without numeric keypad, it's impossible to use it for produce specials characters (e.g.: `Alt + 0231` for the `ç`)

I've tried many solutions, like auto replacement in Microsoft Office (e.g.: `,,c` being replaced by `ç`), but for all my diacritics, I must type a space, then a back space before the replacement work.
I've also tried third party software, as [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/238306/lifehacker-code-texter-windows), but it is very buggy and don't work properly (or don't work at all) in many case!

So, is there a solution somewhere, to have this Mac OS X's nice and comfortable way of producing diacritics for Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest I've found this far is at http://rabbe.tumblr.com/post/23117297936/mac-us-keyboard-layout-for-windows.

**EDIT**: Disregard my comment about the missing modifiers for curly quotes. For some reason, I just had to reboot and then they worked.

Taken from the linked site…

No modifiers

```
` 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 - =
q w e r t y u i o p [ ] \
a s d f g h j k l ; '
z x c v b n m , . /
```

<kbd>Shift</kbd>

```
~ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ +
Q W E R T Y U I O P { } |
A S D F G H J K L : "
Z X C V B N M < > ?
```

<kbd>Option</kbd>

```
` ¡ ™ £ ¢ ∞ § ¶ • ª º – ≠
œ ∑ ´ ® † ¥ ¨ ˆ ø π “ ‘ «
å ß ∂ ƒ © ˙ ∆ ˚ ¬ … æ
Ω ≈ ç √ ∫ ˜ µ ≤ ≥ ÷
```

<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>

```
` ⁄ € ‹ › ﬁ ﬂ ‡ ° · ‚ — ±
Œ „ ´ ‰ ˇ Á ¨ ˆ Ø ∏ ” ’ »
Å Í Î Ï ˝ Ó Ô  Ò Ú Æ
¸ ˛ Ç ◊ ı ˜ Â ¯ ˘ ¿
```

Comment: WOW. Close to perfection, but as the `.klc` is provided it's as if perfection had been reached… Thank you very much!

Comment: [The download links no longer work](http://rabbe.tumblr.com/post/47524855660/hi-jonas-the-download-links-dont-work-anymore-any).

Comment: There is another one here: https://github.com/adunning/Mac-Keyboard-Layouts-for-Windows. The KLC needed some cleanup of the name to pass validation but otherwise it works great.

Answer (score 1):

In the Region options in Control Panel, add the `United States - International` keyboard layout and enable the Language Bar. Select the keyboard layout using the button on the Language Bar, and you can then type `'c` 'to produce a `ç`, for example. You may need to restart Windows (at minimum, you'll need to restart any running applications) for this to take effect.

There are other keyboard layouts that exhibit this behaviour, but I *know* the US-International layout does what you need.

Alternately, you can create/edit a keyboard layout using the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665).

Comment: The problem is that `United States - International` has a different key mapping of my `United States - International (Apple)` keyboard…

Comment: Proprietary keyboard layouts? Really? :I - Is there a screenshot of the Apple keyboard layout anywhere? Might the French Canadian layout work?

Comment: Here it is: [`English International (Apple)`](http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT2841/HT2841-Wireless-International.jpg). I found it here: [Apple KB — How to identify keyboard localizations](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2841)

Comment: Since it isn't a normal keyboard, you may be able to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665 to create the layout you want. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: This will bring all the functionalities of the `United States - International` layout?

Comment: If you "Load existing" first, yes, you'll have all of the US-International functionality, and you can then add or modify whichever keys you need to for the Apple layout (Looks like the only real differences are the ~ and Section-symbol keys).